# Why are double hyphens invalid in HTML comments?

Tags: html, web-standards

Standards mode HTML [forbids double hyphens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/The_Importance_of_Correct_HTML_Commenting) in comments.

```
<!-- This is a perfectly valid comment - I think. -->
<!-- Invalid comment -- definitely. -->
```

There are three additional restrictions, exemplified by these invalid examples:

```
<!--> invalid -->
<!---> invalid -->
<!-- invalid --->
```

Why bother specifying all these little edge cases? In particular, **why forbid double hyphens?**

Comment: Because this is a valid comment `<!-- valid html comment -- > `

Comment: This comes from XML, I think. The rational, if I remember correctly, was to allow it to be parsed with exactly 1 character of lookahead past the current one. Edit: I don't think I remember correctly. Not sure where I got that from :-)

Comment: Interestingly `<html><body><p>This is a test...<!-- Invalid comment -- definitely. -->of the emergency broadcast system.</p></body></html>` renders as *This is a test...of the emergency broadcast system.* just fine in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @J0e3gan all kind of invalid markup will render correctly... doesn't make it valid.

Comment: Invalidity is usually discovered in practice.  Ironically, it actually works in practice.  Regardless, a [simple web search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=double+hyphens+in+html+comment&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=double+hyphens+in+html+comment) turns up the answer...on SO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> [Definition: Comments may appear anywhere in a document outside other
>   markup; in addition, they may appear within the document type
>   declaration at places allowed by the grammar. They are not part of the
>   document's character data; an XML processor may, but need not, make it
>   possible for an application to retrieve the text of comments. For
>   compatibility, the string " -- " (double-hyphen) must not occur within
>   comments.] Parameter entity references must not be recognized within
>   comments.

The grammar does not allow a comment ending in --->

It seems to be a feature of XML included solely to ensure that XML remains compatible with SGML
http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments

Comment: This is a good answer. HTML5 needed to try be a common subset of XML comment syntax, SGML comment syntax, and the comment syntax that browsers supported, all 3 of which were different. Of the 3, SGML was probably least important as browsers never supported SGML comment syntax properly (though validators did). But the resulting product should indeed work in an SGML parser.